# What is the chance of winning on the first or second black red in roulette

Tags: probability

I know the chance of hitting either red or black on the first roll is about 48%
1/37 chance on European 0
But shouldn't the chance of getting it right on either the first or second roll be high

like 66% or 75%

so to bet 25 1st roll and 50 second roll should have about 75% chance of a win?

Comment: Yes, the chances of getting at least one roll right is about 75%

Comment: It seems like you're mixing together some variant of a martingale betting strategy and the gambler's fallacy. A spin of the roulette wheel should be treated as an independent event. If you have a 48% chance of winning on the first spin, whether you win or lose, you have the same chance of winning (and losing) on the subsequent spin.

Answer (score 1):

If the chances of winning on one roll are $\frac{18}{37}$, then the probability of winning *at least once* in two rolls is 
$$1 - (1 - 18/37)^2 \approx 74\%.$$

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider:

- Each spin of the roulette wheel is an independent even. It is a common fallacy for a gambler to reason in the following manner: Because the ball has landed black three times consecutively, I should now bet red since the odds of the ball landing on black a fourth time are very small.  This is false.
- You could consider a geometric distribution if you want to calculate the chance of the $nth$ spin of the wheel producing your first success. Rather than reproduce every bit of information on this distribution, I will provide [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)
- You can use a binomial distribution if you are interested in examining the probability of winning $n$ times at the roulette table in $m$ spins. [Here is information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) on the binomial distribution.